Why KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle uses 100 DML Rows for one article?
Why KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(String, Boolean) uses 100 DML Rows for one article?
I think article record is 1 DML Row, article version another 1 DML row, where are 98 DML Rows are coming from?

Can you share more detail about your implementation? I have a test class using it with no issue.

There indeed seems to be an issue.
Ran this code in dev console and the results are as shown in the comments.
System.debug('DML ROWS LIMIT::' + Limits.getLimitDmlRows());//10000
System.debug('DML ROWS BEFORE::' + Limits.getDmlRows());//0
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle('kA07V000000XpA1SAK', true);
System.debug('DML ROWS PROCESSED AFTER::' + Limits.getDmlRows());//100

Reached out to Salesforce and below is the response from Support Team.
Hope this will be helpful for anyone who sees this issue.
"I have investigated the issue further and could see that there is a limitation with KbManagement.PublishingService where it will consume 100 DML rows due to some internal constraints. Also, the product team has logged a bug to update the below article for the same.
Reference Article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm#apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_publishArticle
As a workaround, could you please use the below method which will use one DML, you can put the scheduled date to null to publish immediately.
KbManagement.PublishingService.scheduleForPublication
"

+1 for taking the time to contact Support and let the Community know

Thanks for contacting Support. I am really tired and exhausted talking to SF support
